# Postgres WHEN case with Select query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a Postgres WHEN case query error. How can I fix the query?

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN  AccountStatus='Open' 
           THEN
             (
              SELECT  * 
               from Accounts
               where statusID=1
             )

        WHEN  AccountType='Mutual'
           THEN
             (
               SELECT *
               FROM Accounts
               WHERE AccountTypeID=2
             )

   END as Status, *
FROM Accounts
```

Showing Error:

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: Please give the table details.

Comment: Those two subqueries, because they are in the SELECT portion of your query, can only return a single value. I suspect you have more than one record in your `Accounts` table that has a `StatusID=1` or `StatusID=2`. How would you suspect it would display MANY records in a single record of your result set? If you share some sample data and your desired results we can guide you to a proper way of getting what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM Accounts
WHERE CASE  WHEN (AccountStatus='Open' ) THEN statusID=1 
            WHEN (AccountType='Mutual')THEN AccountTypeID=2 
      END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not a case query, you want to get the table row given as below. If you really want to use `case when` type query please define the tables in detail.

```
SELECT *, 'Open' AS Status from Accounts where statusID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'Mutual' AS Status FROM Accounts WHERE AccountTypeID = 2
```